Google's "Find My Device" shows confusing, delayed information
My Samsung Android phone was stolen 10 days ago while on vacation in Rome. I used Google's 'Find My Device' from my Android tablet a couple of hours after the theft; it said the phone was in California, which was its location two days prior to the theft. However, I had spent the whole day in Rome using Google Maps on the phone, so obviously there was plenty of network traffic (I had an international cellular voice and data plan on the phone).
The next day, 'Find My Device' said the phone was located at the Vatican which is where we were on the morning of the theft. Then later that day, 'Find My Device' told me the phone was located at the Rome Termini train station, which is where the theft actually occurred.
So my question is, is it normal for Google's 'Find My Device' to be so out of date (delayed) in terms of location when the phone was obviously very active in terms of GPS and network?

By "find my phone", did you mean Find your phone from Google Account, or Find My Device? I assumed the latter? Also, is it the web app, or the Android app?

I believe you are correct - 'Find My Device', Android app; confusingly labeled 'Find Device' on the main screen!  I'm normally a desktop user and I'm finding it very hard to type on this tablet so I appreciate your corrections.
